# ADC Converter not reading value on STM32L432KCU6

Tags: stm32, adc, stm32cubeide

Morning guys! I'm writing a program on my STM32 microcontroller; by means of a potentiometer connected to pin PA3. It is meant to read the value (between 0V and 3.3V) and change the blinking period of a led connected to pin PA1. My ADC has been configured to have 12 bits so the value it reads will be between 0 and 4055. The code I've written is:

```
uint32_t ADC_value = 0;
uint32_t led_period = 2.5;
uint32_t conversion_factor = 0.000805664; // 3.3V/2^12 = 8.05664e-4, es el valor que necesito
//para convertir el valor del adc (adc_value) a volts.

void GPIO_Config(void);
void ADC_Config(void);
void TIM2_Config(void);
void TIM6_Config(void);
void Read_ADC(void);
void delay_us(uint32_t wait);
void delay_ms(uint32_t wait);

void ADC_Config(void)
{
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_ADCEN; // habilito ADC clock [Page 218, Sec 6.4.16]
    RCC->CCIPR |= RCC_CCIPR_ADCSEL_0;
    RCC->CCIPR |= RCC_CCIPR_ADCSEL_1; // setea el clock del sistema como el clock del ADC

    // Common Control Register
    ADC1_COMMON->CCR &= ~ADC_CCR_PRESC_Msk;
    ADC1_COMMON->CCR |= (0B0010 << ADC_CCR_PRESC_Pos); // seteado en 0010
    //CKMode por defecto 00, no se toca

    // Control Register
    ADC1->CR &= ~ADC_CR_DEEPPWD; // ADC not in Deep-power down
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN; // ADC volt regulator enable
    delay_ms(1); // Deberia esperar 20useg, espero 1ms.
    //HAL_Delay(1);
    ADC1->CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADEN; // deshabilito ADC para configuracion

    // Configuration Register
    ADC1->CFGR &= ~ADC_CFGR_RES; // resolucion de 12-bit [Page 461]

    // Sample Time Register
    //NOTA: Alejandro hace la observacion que aqui debajo va channel 8
    //ADC1->SMPR1 |= (0B1000 << ADC_SMPR1_SMP1_Pos); // linea original, modifico abajo
    ADC1->SMPR1 |= (0B010 << ADC_SMPR1_SMP8_Pos); // seteo a channel 8 como dijo Alejandro


    // Regular Sequence Register
    ADC1->SQR1 &= ~ADC_SQR1_L; // set one conversion
    ADC1->SQR1 |= ADC_SQR1_SQ1_0 | ADC_SQR1_SQ1_1; // setea conversion sequence para canal 3, basicamente dice que lea del canal 3 [Page 468]

    // Control Register
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADCAL; // calibracion del ADC. Necesario para mejorar las lecturas. [Page 454]
    while((ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADCAL)); // espero la terminacion de la calibracion.  [Page 454]
}

void Read_ADC(void){
    // instrucciones en [Page 386]
    ADC1->ISR |= ADC_ISR_ADRDY; // limpio ADRDY seteandolo en 1
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN; // habilito ADC una vez terminada la configuracion y calibracion
    //while(~(ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRDY)); // espero al ADC para que este listo. [Page 451]
    delay_ms(1);

    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART;

    while(~(ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC) == 0); // espero al fin de la conversion

    ADC_value = ADC1->DR;

    // limpio EOS y ADRDY
    ADC1->ISR |= ADC_ISR_EOS;
    ADC1->ISR |= ADC_ISR_ADRDY;
}

void GPIO_Config(void)
{
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN; // habilito GPIOA clock [Page 218, Sec 6.4.16]

    // PA1 CONFIG
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE1_1;
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE1_0; // seteo PA1 a output mode
    GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR1); // deshabilito pull-up/pull-down
    GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS1; // set bit 1 in the GPIOA output data register

    // PA3 CONFIG
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE3; // seteo PA3 a analog mode
}

void TIM2_Config(void)
{
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_TIM2EN; // habilito TIM2 clock. [Page 220]

    TIM2->PSC = 800-1; // seteo prescaler para 80MHz / 800 = 100kHz
    TIM2->ARR = 100000; // auto-reload register en 100k. Interrupt sucede cada 1 seg
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE; // habilitar auto-reload preload
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS; // update en overflow. [Page 863]
    TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE; // habilitar update interrupt
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; // habilitar timer

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn); // habilitar interrupcion TIM2_IRQn
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0);
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if((TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_UIF) != 0){
        TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF; // reseteo el flag de interrupcion de update
        Read_ADC();
        led_period = 2.5 + ADC_value/4095*2; // led_period puede ir entre [2, 4]
    }
}

void TIM6_Config(void)
{
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_TIM6EN; // habilito TIM6 clock. [Page 220]

    TIM6->PSC = 8000-1; // seteo prescaler para 80MHz / 8000 = 10kHz
    TIM6->ARR = led_period * 10000; // auto-reload register en 100k. Interrupt sucede cada 2.5 seg
    TIM6->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE; // habilitar auto-reload preload
    TIM6->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS; // update en overflow. [Page 863]
    TIM6->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE; // habilitar update interrupt
    TIM6->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; // habilitar timer

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM6_IRQn, 0);
}

void TIM6_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if((TIM6->SR & TIM_SR_UIF) != 0){
        TIM6->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF; // reseteo el flag de interrupcion de update
        if (GPIOA->ODR & GPIO_ODR_OD1){
            GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR1;
        } else {
            GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS1;
        }

    }
}

void delay_us(uint32_t wait){
    SysTick->LOAD = wait*10;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
    while(!(SysTick->CTRL & SysTick_CTRL_COUNTFLAG_Msk));
}

void delay_ms(uint32_t wait){
    for (uint32_t i = wait; i > 0; i--)
        delay_us(1000);
}

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  GPIO_Config();
  ADC_Config();
  TIM2_Config();
  TIM6_Config();

  while (1)
  {
      /*
      GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS1;
      delay_ms(2500);
      GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR1;
      */
  }
}
```

The value I'm reading on the ADC does not change, it always reads a value of 100 or 90. I believe the issue is comming along either with the configuration of the ADC on ADC_Config() function or the reading process on Read_ADC().

Comment: You could be right.

Comment: Don't put delays in interrupt handlers. And I think your delay_us function doesn't work. `Countflag` returns 1 if `VAL` hits zero, and you are writing `VAL` with zero right before checking. SysTick is a downcounter.